# How to retrieve the data from SQL and display in ModalPopup

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I've tried to view the data in a modal popup when I click the calendar control. I used the following code:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#003399" Height="500px" OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender" Width="500px" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" CellPadding="1">
    <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" Height="1px" ForeColor="#336666" />
    <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
    <SelectorStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" />
    <TitleStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" Height="25px" />
    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="White" />
    <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" />
</asp:Calendar>

</div>
<div>
    <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="#EAEAEA" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" Height="200px" Width="300px" Direction="LeftToRight" Font-Names="Calibri" BackImageUrl="~/Image/index2.jpg">
        <div>
            <div style="height:120px; width:300px;">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Date"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lbl_date" runat="server" Text="16-06-2014"></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Time"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lbl_time" runat="server" Text="07:00 PM"></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Day"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lbl_day" runat="server" Text="Monday"></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lbl_msg" runat="server" Text="Staff Meeting"></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div style="height:40px; width:300px">
                <asp:Image ID="Image_imgages" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="50px" Visible="false" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btn_close" runat="server" Text="Close" />
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>

    <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="Calendar1" DropShadow="True">
```

Here my problem is the modal popup is not bringing the data from database. When I remove the `ModalPopupExtender` the data are displaying in the panel.
Can some one help me in this part.

Comment: I don't think I understand hiding the popup and data displaying in the panel. According to `PopupControlID="Panel1"`, the panel is the popup. Do you mean when you remove or comment-out `ModalPopupExtender1` then the panel displays the data, and does not popup correctly otherwise? (Also to note, `ModalPopupExtender1` should have `CancelControlID="btn_close"` according to your code.)

Comment: yes, u r correct, if I comment the modalpopupextender, the panel retrieve the data

Comment: @MikeGuthrie  can u help at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin, I'll explain why it works without `ModalPopupExtender` and did not work with it. The `ModalPopupExtender` registers a javascript event to grab the `SelectionChanged` of `Calendar1` and then shows the `Panel1`. This all happens client-side, with no postback, thus the field values of `Panel1` were never changing.

Removing the `ModalPopupExtender` allowed `Calendar1.SelectionChanged` to be handled as normal, on a postback. What you are after is a solution that both puts `Panel1` into a popup *and* performs an async postback to put the new values into `Panel1`. I think this may typically be done by setting up a service, and filling the proper values for the `Dynamic...` properties of `ModalPopupExtender`. However, a much simpler way, using everything you already have in place, is just to use an `UpdatePanel`, as I show here:

```
<div>
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" DayNameFormat="Shortest" 
        Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#003399" Height="500px" OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender" Width="500px" 
        OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" CellPadding="1">
        <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" Height="1px" ForeColor="#336666" />
        <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
        <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
        <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
        <SelectorStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" />
        <TitleStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" Height="25px" />
        <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="White" />
        <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" />
    </asp:Calendar>
</div>
<div>
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="#EAEAEA" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" Height="200px" Width="300px" 
                Direction="LeftToRight" Font-Names="Calibri" BackImageUrl="~/Image/index2.jpg">
                <div style="height:120px; width:300px;">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Date"></asp:Label></td>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lbl_date" runat="server" Text="16-06-2014"></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Time"></asp:Label></td>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lbl_time" runat="server" Text="07:00 PM"></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Day"></asp:Label></td>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lbl_day" runat="server" Text="Monday"></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lbl_msg" runat="server" Text="Staff Meeting"></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div style="height:40px; width:300px">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image_imgages" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="50px" Visible="false" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btn_close" runat="server" Text="Close" />
                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenField1" />
                <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="HiddenField1"
                    CancelControlID="btn_close" DropShadow="True">
                </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Calendar1" EventName="SelectionChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

In this way, you don't need to change anything else, except to modify your handler for your calendar selection as so:

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Your original code here, plus at the end:
    ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
}
```

Comment: @user3744938 Glad I could help. And I understand the initial problem, since it got me at first, too: by `ModalPopupExtender` being part of the AJAX Toolkit, your first instinct is to assume the contents will be updated via ajax automatically.

Comment: I have another doubt, in my calendar control I want to make click only to the date which has events, in my calendar I can able to click all. how to set remaining date unclickable.

Comment: I don't think it's functionality built-in to the basic ASP.Net Calendar control. I did a web search and [came across this as a possibility](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/15633-How-disable-color-specific-date-Range.aspx). Another option is to use [jQuery Datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/), but you'll have to check the Form values manually to get the value in that case.

Comment: what is the difference between .mdb file and .accdb file, I want to retrieve the data from MS Access file, I created the file but its shows the .accdb extension, I want to create it as .mdb and also how to give the connection for oledb